# Properly display content from a php file into a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm working on a wordpress plugin which needs to show and handle user signups at some point. I already made the page and added a shortcode like `[signup-page]` as its content.

Now, what I would like to do is turn this shortcode to the actual signup form located in the plugin directory.

The plugin has a class that handles inner workings including actions like (added in the class contructor):

```
add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'register_menus'));
add_filter('plugin_action_links', array(&$this, 'add_action_link'), 10, 2);
```

and they work fine.

I also added `add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'load_view'), 100);` with the related method:

```
function load_view($content){
   if(preg_match('#\[signup-page\]#is', $content))
   {
      return 'REGISTRATION FORM HERE!';
   }
   return $content;
}
```

However, this filter is not working! and I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: FYI, this is not how you add short codes. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I suggest to make your comment an answer, vicvicvic, since it answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `[signup-page]` is your `shortcode` in the page/post content and if so then you can use

```
if(stristr($content, '[signup-page]'))
{
    $reg_form="<form action=''>";
    $reg_form.="<input />";
    // ...
    return $reg_form;
}
return $content;
```

But the proper way to use `shortcode` is (basically in your functions.php)

```
function myShortCodeGenerator($atts)
{
    // ...
}
add_shortcode( 'signup-page', 'msShortCodeGenerator' ); // myShortCodeGenerator function will execute whenever wordpress finds [signup-page]
```

[**Read More**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: it's not showing even if I just make if(true) return 'REGISTRATION FORM HERE!';

Comment: thank you for the tips about the shortcode" clean "way ! it works fine!